# Зависает приложение калькулятор при нажатии кнопки

Tags: swift

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема ошибка:unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
при нажатии на кнопку калькулятор зависает
ошибка в этой строке numberOnScreen = Double(label.text!)!

import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
 var numberOnScreen:Double = 0

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func numbers(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    label.text = label.text! + String(sender.tag-1)
    numberOnScreen = Double(label.text!)!
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего `label.text == nil` когда вы обращаетесь к нему в первый раз. Из за этого происходит ошибка

Можете попробовать следующее:

```
if let _text = label.text {
    label.text = _text + String(sender.tag-1)

    if let number = Double(_text){
        numberOnScreen = number
    }
}
```

Comment: не помогло та же ошибка

Comment: скорее всего значение из _text невозможно преобразовать в double. Попробуйте if let number = Double(_text) { numberOnScreen = number }

Comment: Зачем используете tag ?, Что находится в title вашей кнопки ?